# How to check if remote file is newer in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, filesystems, client-server

I've written an Android app which populates the UI via data from an XML feed.

The feed contains pretty standard information. Which category each item is in plus thumbnail and title of every category or item. The app is finished, basically, but I would like to store thumbnails on the local device.

If I do this, what can I run on a URL to ask, "Is there a thumbnail on file? Is this thumbnail different/newer than the one already on file?"

Also, I assume I will be calling on some local URI to recall thumbnails from filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a PHP server you can use the NameValuePairs to send POST data from the android device; when you download the thumbnails the first time store some info into a small database (time of image upload for example); attach this information to your HttpRequest, and the PHP server can check the server-database if there are newer thumbnails or not.